# The insert query working in mysql phpmyadmin isn't working when I try it using php mysqli or wpdb

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert a row into a table using $wpdb. When i run the code

```
    $wpdb->insert( 'sync_orders', $data);
$last_query = $wpdb->last_query;
```

It shows error 'you have an error in mysql syntax'. I am fetching the last query and when I run that query into phpmyadmin, the query is working fine.

I thought that $wpdb is having some problem, so I tried that same query using mysqli_query(). But here again I got same problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. : not using the third param $format in $wpdb->insert() as I am inserting all the values as string.

This is the query I am getting from $wpdb

```
INSERT INTO `sync_orders` (`post_author`, `post_title`, `post_date`, `post_status`, `order_key`, `order_currency`, `prices_include_tax`, `customer_ip_address`, `customer_user_agent`, `customer_user`, `created_via`, `cart_hash`, `order_version`, `billing_first_name`, `billing_last_name`, `billing_company`, `billing_email`, `billing_phone`, `billing_country`, `billing_address_1`, `billing_address_2`, `billing_city`, `billing_state`, `billing_postcode`, `shipping_first_name`, `shipping_last_name`, `shipping_company`, `shipping_country`, `shipping_address_1`, `shipping_address_2`, `shipping_city`, `shipping_state`, `shipping_postcode`, `payment_method`, `payment_method_title`, `order_shipping`, `cart_discount`, `cart_discount_tax`, `order_tax`, `order_shipping_tax`, `order_total`, `download_permissions_granted`, `recorded_sales`, `order_stock_reduced`, `edit_lock`, `order_item_name`, `order_item_type`, `qty`, `tax_class`, `product_id`, `variation_id`, `line_subtotal`, `line_total`, `line_subtotal_tax`, `line_tax`, `line_tax_data`, `pa_color`, `pa_size`) VALUES (1, 'Order &ndash; February 3, 2017 @ 01:08 PM', '2017-02-03 13:08:50', 'wc-processing', 'wc_order_58948091938b0', 'INR', 'no', '127.0.0.1', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0', '1', 'checkout', '3229e8ee0da4d8ed89d879f4a1ba9dea', '2.6.13', 'sasdf', 'asdf', 'asdfasdf asdf', 'sharad.kalya@techinfini.in', '7565465455', 'IN', 'asdff adf ffasdf', 'asdfsadf sadf', 'goa', 'GA', '454545', 'sasdf', 'asdf', 'asdfasdf asdf', 'IN', 'asdff adf ffasdf', 'asdfsadf sadf', 'goa', 'GA', '454545', 'cod', 'Cash on Delivery', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '450.00', '1', 'yes', '1', '1487087216:1', 'Product - 1', 'line_item', '1', '', '9', '20', '450', '450', '0', '0', 'a:2:{s:5:\\\"total\\\";a:0:{}s:8:\\\"subtotal\\\";a:0:{}}', 'brown', 'medium')
```

Comment: can you put your query here also, to see what could go wrong?

Comment: does your sql query end with a ; ? it should, but you have not posted it here.

Comment: This is the query returned by $wpdb and I have posted it as it was. But also when I am trying to use this query with mysqli_query() or mysql_query(), I am appending a ; at the end of it. In anyways it is not working.

Comment: please define "not working". You get an error? Or it doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: what version of php do you have? can you check if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled? it might mess up your query when it is passed to mysqli_query() as a string.

Comment: @ADyson Actually query framed is alright but when I try firing that query using php code, I get an error.

Comment: @moni_dragu The version of php installed is 5.5.3 and also magic_quotes_dpc are DISABLED.

Comment: @S.kalya Do you get exactly the same error regardless if you use mysqli_query, mysql_query or the `$wpdb->insert`? or different errors?

Comment: Yes, I get always same error - "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`' at line 1]"